# If you buy your own iPhone app, will it delete the developers build currently on your device?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

So probably somewhat of a stupid question but here it goes.

If you download your own app once it gets submitted to the app store, will it download and overwrite the development build I currently still have on my device?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes,

It will install on anything that has the same bundle ID. The bundle ID is something like `com.yourcompany.youappname`.

If you want to, you can change the bundle ID in your development version and keep the one you have in the store. They can coexist that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot gcamp, that is exactly what I assumed would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is the same bundle id it will overwrite the app. However all resource files will be preserved (NSUserDefaults, Documents directory files, etc)

Comment: Are you sure about this?  Meaning all sqlite database contents will be preserved as well when you buy the app?  This was my only concern, thanks